# git branches in separate folders

Tags: php, wordpress, git

Been searching for this a while, but haven't found anything that clears it up.

I'm working on a wordpress theme. And the theme will be deployed on 3 different places on my domain. So i need 3 branches:

1. Master branch - located at domain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
   (/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme)
2. Develop branch - located at dev.domain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
   (/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/mytheme)
3. Test branch - located at demo.domain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
   (public_html/demo/wp-content/themes/mytheme)

The idea here is that every time i make changes to the dev branch, i can push it to master and demo.

So i'm wondering how i set this up ? Do i use worktree, or...?
Not sure how to proceed to get this setup. If anyone got another solution on how to this, i'm open for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, really. Create a repository, within it, create three branches: master, develop and test. Now, every time you work on a feature, push it to develop branch. Every time you want to push the changes to either master or test, simply merge develop branch to the appropriate branch. Now, when you deploy your code onto your environments, make sure to always deploy master theme from master branch etc.

Basically, what you're looking for is a proper git workflow. Check out [this page](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows), it might clarify the ideas behind workflows in git a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link, I'm kinda new to git, and trying to wrap my head around it all. When you say "Now, when you deploy your code onto your environments, make sure to always deploy master theme from master branch etc." i'm not following. Do I clone the "master" repo.git in to the develop and test folders ?

Comment: You check out master branch and copy the resulting files into your production environment, check out develop branch and copy the files into your dev environment and same thing with test.

Comment: ok, but cant i "skip" the copying of files, if i have my branches in the different folders ? If i clone the repo to the correct folder, and checkout the appropriate / corresponding branch?

Comment: The idea behind branches is that you don't have 3 separate folders... also, you probably don't want your config to be taken directly from the repository - you should have some sort of deployment script that would deploy the appropriate config to appropriate place. This allows any kind of versioning of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the normal git setup? Create the three branches you've mentionned:

1. Master
2. Develop
3. Test

Whenever you're done with the features you've added to your test branch, simply create a merge request.

If you don't know how to create a merge request, here's the Gitlab documentation: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html

The source branch would be your `Test` branch, and the other one would be your `Master` or `Develop` branch.

Comment: Thanks for your tip and answer, i'm new to this git thing, and trying to wrap my head around it all. Do i clone the master repo into the develop and test folders ?

Comment: No problem @JøranSørbø. You can simply checkout from the git on your Master branch, then create a new branch for Develop and Test. It should take the files you currently have on your Master branch.